# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() + Up Arrow?

Tags: android

We can use the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` method on an activity to display the "up" arrow on the action bar.

If I understand correctly, we're only really supposed to show the up arrow if we're not the root activity.

Clicking the "up" arrow should take us to the root activity. Is that all there is to it? I should then add this call to all my activities like so:

```
class RootActivity {
    public void onCreate() {
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
}

class AppleActivity {
    public void onCreate() {
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

class OrangeActivity {
    public void onCreate() {
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty much it.

Clicking the up-arrow should take you towards the root.

and don't forget to actually handle the click in [onOptionsItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) by checking the item id against `android.R.id.home`

Comment: Hi, one distinction I'm not clear on - is hitting the up-arrow supposed to clear the entire activity stack and jump the user back to the root activity? (I think it is, and they use the back-key if they want to go backwards in the stack instead). Thanks!

Comment: No, not necessarily. You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)